# frozen ubuntu resulted in hard drive failure?

Tags: boot

During installation ubuntu froze. I know all my data on the other drive is gone. So I put a new one in. I get the error Insert Boot media. I have gone into the BIOS and fixed everything. Please help me out :|

Comment: There are not a lot of details in your question : version, how did you start the installation (CD, USB, Wubi, ...), what do you do in the BIOS, error output, ...

Comment: The problems are solved lol sorry for being generic and I love ubuntu -Peace :)